# USB IR remote wakup from Suspend

Tags: 14.04, usb, suspend, xbmc

I am running 14.04 XBMCbuntu and am a new user. I have got xbmc installed the way I want it and have an MCE remote setup.

I have got suspend working but the wake is only via the keyboard not IR Remote or mouse.

I have read up on a range of forums to find the answer and tried a number of things.

When I run cat /proc/acpi/wakeup

I get a list of items but no USB01 or USB02 files..... in spite of this I have tried

```
echo USB0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup

echo USB1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup

echo USB2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup

echo USB3 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

When I run lsusb

The device is there `@ Bus02 Device 08: 0471:o60c Philips (or NXP) eHome Infrared Receiver`

I have tried to edit the `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2` power files to "enabled" however get error messages about failing to save a backup and thus can't write the file!

Any support would be appreciated on the following fronts:

1. getting the ir receiver to Wake
2. edit the sys files noted above
3. I can't copy from xterm into the browser. I can copy from browser to xterm using Shift Insert, and can copy from one xterm to another xterm screen using control shift c and Shift Insert....

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and was also stumped by my USBs not appearing in /proc/acpi/wakeup. In the end, however, despite many solutions suggesting this was required I did not need to enable USBs in ACPI.

Instead, enabling wakeup on the USB port my IR device was connected to was was enough.

Find your device ID:

```
$ lsusb
```

> Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp.
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp.
>   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>   Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13ba:0018 PCPlay Barcode PCP-BCG4209
>   **Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1934:5168 Feature Integration Technology Inc. (Fintek) F71610A or F71612A Consumer Infrared Receiver/Transceiver**
>   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

In the above example my device ID is **5168**.

Grep /sys/bus/usb to find the port your device is plugged into:

```
$ grep 5168 /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/idProduct
```

> /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-13/idProduct:5168

This indicates my device is plugged into bus3, port 13.

Confirm the port is correct:

```
$lsusb -t
```

> /:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
>   **/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/14p, 480M
>
>      |__ Port 13: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=mceusb, 12M**
>      |__ Port 14: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
>      |__ Port 14: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
>   /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
>       |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
>   /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
>      |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M

Bus 3, port 13 matches the bus/port returned by grep (3-13)

Check if wakeup is enabled:

```
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-13/power/wakeup
```

> disabled

Enable wakeup on port:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "enabled" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-13/power/wakeup'
```

Check if wakeup enabled:

```
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-13/power/wakeup
```

> enabled

Test your device, does it wake the system?

Make this change persistent across reboots:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add the following lines after the comments and before 'exit 0'

```
# Enable Wake on IR for USB bus 3 port 13.  
echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-13/power/wakeup
```

Now happily wake your PC from your USB device.

**Limitations**
One problem with this approach is that if the USB port the IR device is plugged into changes, then enabling that port specifically does not help.

[This post](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=104541&pid=1948050#pid1948050) has a way of enabling any IR port based on the device that is plugged into it using a Udev rule.

**References**
[Kodi, MCE Remote and Ubuntu](http://jakobsens.net/?p=770%22Kodi,%20MCE%20Remote%20and%20Ubuntu%22)
[Wake from suspend with keyboard or mouse](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1938480&p=11940008#post11940008%22Wake%20from%20suspend%20with%20keyboard%20or%20mouse%22)
[Enabling IR devices with a Udev rule](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=104541&pid=1948050#pid1948050)

Comment: Good solution, but in my case it works only when IR-receiver connected via external 4 ports passive USB-hub.