# Why does wake from suspend with wireless mouse continue to fail?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, xps

I've been slamming my head over this issue. According to previous up-voted methods: [askubuntu_link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088726/how-to-use-a-key-press-to-wake-a-suspended-laptop-when-using-a-kvm-switch) and similarly [askubuntu_link2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848698/wake-up-from-suspend-using-wireless-usb-keyboard-or-mouse-for-any-linux-distro), I enable power/wakeup to the usb device connected to my wireless mouse receiver and also attempt to create udev rules for my specific device. However, I still can't get any wakeup response from my wireless mouse upon suspend; I'm only able to wake up by opening the laptop lid and wake using the touchpad. My laptop is a Dell XPS 13 9380 with Ubuntu 18.04.

I begin:

```
$ grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup
```

Initially yielding,

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-7/power/wakeup:disabled    
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-9/power/wakeup:disabled   
/sys/bus/usb/devices/5-1/power/wakeup:disabled   
/sys/bus/usb/devices/6-1.2/power/wakeup:disabled   
/sys/bus/usb/devices/6-1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb4/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb5/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb6/power/wakeup:disabled
```

Finding the usb port for my wireless receiver:

```
$ lsusb

Bus 006 Device 004: ID 0480:a006 Toshiba America Inc External Disk 1.5TB  
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.  
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0424:5807 Standard Microsystems Corp.   
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270  
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0bda:4014 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.   
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0424:2807 Standard Microsystems Corp.    
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub   
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub    
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub   
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub   
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e0a2 Foxconn / Hon Hai    
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:6723 Microdia        
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I identify my device ID is **c534**.

Find the port my device is plugged into:

```
$ grep c534 /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/idProduct  

/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-9/idProduct:c534
```

This indicates my device is plugged into bus 1, port 9.

Double-check if wakeup is enabled:

```
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-9/power/wakeup  
disabled
```

Enable wakeup on port:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "enabled" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-9/power/wakeup'
```

Check if wakeup enabled:
    $ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-9/power/wakeup 
    enabled

Upon testing the computer in suspend mode, I get no wake up.

Then, I attempt editing wakeup rules specific to my device:

```
$ lsusb | grep Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID **046d:c534** Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

Using device id's, I edit number 10 priority `udev` rules for usb port 1-9:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-wakeup.rules

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c534" RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-9/power/wakeup'"
```

After system restart, and checking that port 1-9 has wakeup enabled, I continue to get no response from my mouse under computer suspend. WHY??? I'm stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt to help. But no, I've tried unplugging and plugging the logitech unifying receiver with many variations as well, and I still can't get a response out of suspend.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I still am unable to get the desired unwake with mouse result. Could you please help me debug? I create your script, change the device id to mine, mark file executable. I get no desired change when I suspend my computer. When testing the script manually, I am able to disable mouse response completely but passing resume does not repower the mouse as you already seem to anticipate. Can you assist? Please see my screen capture: https://imgur.com/a/9Xc2MRE (Bus 001 Device 004) Unplugging and plugging receiver does nothing.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I tried with the new script but it still failed. See your submitted answer for details on my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that on Dell (probably not unique to Dell) the usb is disable by default for wakeup on BIOS level. I tried and tried to run the great solutions above without any luck and then I found out the "trivial" answer of bios change.

Answer (score 0):

### Mouse receiver needs power

Your Unifying Receiver needs to be plugged into a USB port that has power when the machine is suspended. You can move your mouse but if the Unifying Receiver has no power nothing will happen.

From: [USB PowerShare not working on XPS13 9380](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/USB-PowerShare-not-working-on-XPS13-9380/td-p/7298666)

> 1. Make sure you actually enabled USB PowerShare in the BIOS Setup interface.  On some systems it's disabled by default.
> 2. Make sure you're using a port that actually supports PowerShare.  Not all Dell systems have PowerShare implemented on all of their USB
>      ports.  Look for a port with a battery icon or possibly a lightning
>      bolt icon, although the latter might cause some confusion because the
>      9380 also supports Thunderbolt 3, which uses a very similar
>      lightning-style icon.
> 3. On some Dell systems, PowerShare only works when the system is either shut down **and on AC power**, or sleeping (on either battery
>      or AC power).  Not all systems enable PowerShare while the system is
>      fully shut down and not plugged in.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help attempts. I tried moving any previous script attempts. Then I created the script, copied the lines of code exactly, marked the file executable, and restarted computer. Upon computer suspend, still no response...

Comment: @Martin Sorry I totally misread your question. I've posted an entirely new answer and removed my previous comments.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in responding to your help. As a post in that link states, there is not specific settings in the BIOS that enables/disables usb powershare but I did change in the BIOS "Uncheck Wake on Dell USB C dock". I can confirm powershare works on the ports that I have tested because they are able to charge my phone during suspend mode. However, when I continue to attempt waking by shaking my mouse and signalling to my USB wireless receiver I still get no response to wake my computer.

Answer (score 0):

`/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup` also needs to be enabled.